# Why when stopping a program in Xcode do you always get a 'program exited abnormally' warning?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Does anyone know why when stopping a program running in the iPhone/iPad simulator in Xcode you always get an error on the debug console of the following format:

`2/2/12 6:09:36.973 PM SpringBoard: Application '<Application Name>' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9`

How do you exit the program normally?  The only reason I ask is because it's pretty annoying sorting through output to the console between application runs with these messages clogging everything up.

Comment: Does this happen when (a) you quit the app by clicking the simulator's Home button, (b) you quit the app by quitting the simulator, or (c) you quit the app by hitting the Stop button in Xcode while the simulator is running? In the latter case, you may be able to avoid the messages by taking one of the former two steps. :)

Comment: quiting the app using methods a and c both display the message.

Comment: That happens because the stop button sends a kill -9 signal to the app. And that is in effect an abnormal exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is an Xcode 4 bug. I usually get an error telling me that my application exited abnormally or I'll get a SIGTERM/SIGABRT on the main function in main.m which is especially annoying because it switches my code editor to the main.m file.

Comment: the worst is getting a bootstrap error (because the debugger is still hung from the previous run) and having to restart your computer to kill the process attached to your user (launchd)